# Rank ordering xts objects representing some property of equities using R

Tags: r, finance, rank, xts

I am trying to rank order equities (by return for example). As a result I would like to receive a table containing names of stocks in ascending/descending order (parameter to this rank order function) with proper handling of NAs (moved at the end of each row). I really can't figure out an elegant way to do this.

Below is an example of what I want:

This is coredata of xts object representing some property at different times:

```
           john    joe     tina    jack    suzie   sasha   sven    luca   
2003-05-29 1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8  
2003-06-27 2       3       4       5       6       7       8       1  
2003-07-30 3       4       5       6       7       8       1       2
2003-07-31 NA      2       3       4       5       6       1       NA
```

I need a dataframe which in each row (for each date) displays the column name from previous dataframe of best ranked (based on a property) in column 1, second best in column 2,... Please note that for the last row I need cases with NAs moved to the end (last two columns) or skipped...

```
           [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    [,7]    [,8]   
2003-05-29 "john"  "joe"   "tina"  "jack"  "suzie" "sasha" "sven"  "luca"  
2003-06-27 "luca"  "john"  "joe"   "tina"  "jack"  "suzie" "sasha" "sven"
2003-07-30 "sven"  "luca"  "john"  "joe"   "tina"  "jack"  "suzie" "sasha"
2003-07-31 "sven"  "joe"   "tina"  "jack"  "suzie" "sasha" "john"  "luca"
```

Thanks in advance for your help. Being a beginner in R this poses to hard of a problem for me...

Kind regards,
Samo.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `m` is your original matrix (i.e. the coredata of the xts). You can then get what you want with:

```
> nams <- colnames(m)
> t( apply(m, 1, function(r) nams[ order(r) ] ) )
           [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]    [,6]    [,7]    [,8]   
2003-05-29 "john" "joe"  "tina" "jack" "suzie" "sasha" "sven"  "luca" 
2003-06-27 "luca" "john" "joe"  "tina" "jack"  "suzie" "sasha" "sven" 
2003-07-30 "sven" "luca" "john" "joe"  "tina"  "jack"  "suzie" "sasha"
2003-07-31 "sven" "joe"  "tina" "jack" "suzie" "sasha" "john"  "luca"
```

Note that `order(r)` converts a vector `r` to a vector `p` such that the sequence
`r[p[1]], r[ p[2] ], r[ p[3] ], ...` is in non-decreasing order, and the default is to push NAs to the end.

Comment: Thanks. Very elegant. I used more than 20 lines of code for doing something simmilar... Well, how to make this arranged in each row in decreasing order with NAs at the end? The thing is that you never know how many NAs were and would need a way to know which is best, second best, third,... Thnx. Samo.

Comment: To sort in decreasing order, replace the `order(r)` above with `order(-r)`.